# How to mount local volume hostPath with AKS?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to create a Kubernetes pod and mounting a volume from local hostpath. I am using Azure Kubernetes cluster. Following is my yaml for creating pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.7.9
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /opt/myfolder
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: /Users/kkadam/minikube/myfolder
      # this field is optional
```

I have few files under `myfolder` which I want to use inside container. Files are present in local volume but not inside container.

What could be an issue?

Comment: is you pod scheduled on same node as where you have the hostPath !!

Comment: No. I was doing this from my local system.

Comment: Can you explain your setup more !!

Comment: Hi @KomalKadam, I guess you got confused with local machine (i.e. you pc) and the host (i.e. the node that forms the cluster). The `hostPath` is node directory. When you test something on minikube, both are the same. But here, they aren't.

Comment: if you can add output of `kubectl get pod -o wide`

Comment: Hi Komal, by local do you mean node path ?

Comment: @DT. This is the output
test-pd                                      1/1     Running   0          89m   10.244.2.41   aks-agentpool-29453832-vmss000000   <none>           <none>

Comment: @HarshManvar I meant from my local system, not from the nodes. But I guess I will have to make sure that folder which I mapping for hostPath should exist on node

Comment: You should create host path on `aks-agentpool-29453832-vmss000000` and copy your data to that hostPath on aks node .. in short host path on your local laptop will not be mounted on AKS .. also note every time your pod is rebuild it can choose a different node and hostPath is node specific .. so if you are looking for persistent data across restarts of container you need to use nfs kind of solution ..

Answer (score 2):

Judging by what you said in your comment and your config, especially the path `/Users/kkadam/minikube/myfolder` which is typically a Mac OS path, it seems that you're trying to mount your local volume (probably your mac) in a pod deployed on AKS.
That's the problem.

In order to make it work, you need to put the files you're trying to mount on the node running your pod (which is in AKS).

Comment: Can you also add the process, how she can move the data to the node directory?

Comment: Using `scp` I guess ? Or whatever solution he/she use to connect to AKS

Comment: ok. Do I have to make sure the folder which I am mapping on hostPath exists on master node?

Comment: No, it has to exist on **the node that is running the pod**. Which means, as @Harsh Manvar said, you have to be sure that the pod will be scheduled on the right node.

Comment: @KomalKadam To make sure, that your pod will be scheduled on a specific node, you can use something like [nodeSelector or node Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/)

Comment: This is a non-answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can not add local path to container running on AKS. You have to add the file on specific node where POD is scheduled.

If both are on same node POD and files then you can mount the files as  the volume to the container and use it.

However if your POD is schedule to another node then you will not be able to access the files inside the container.

If due to any reason your node restarted or deleted during auto-scaling you might lose the data.